# How to move from one action to another and controller to another in sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have done some work on sencha like for one controller actions and views but now i want to start work on multiple controller ,actions and views, how can i give links for call particular controller view in sencha just like master page in asp .net mvc application.....

Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Sandy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your controllers can have listeners defined to interact with particular views within your application, so this will be pretty much the same as what you've done with the single controller, just expanded across logical sections of your site.

Regarding how you "glue" these together via interactions within your applications (e.g., a user clicking a link to navigate to a new section of the site), there are any number of ways to go. I would highly recommend implementing something like [Ext.ux.Router](https://github.com/brunotavares/Ext.ux.Router) to help with this. Whether by using this or rolling something similar of your own, you can create logical and robust routing within your application that can be the impetus for your controllers and views to change and be aware of state.

Comment: Yeah..... Ext.ux.Router it is just totally amazing.... like in mvc application global.ajax file which create routing table for our application same in extjs using this file we can create route table for our extjs application